# AWS SAM lambda destination

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I am a newbie to AWS Serverless Architecture. I would like to use lambda to do something and then send the result to SQS. I would like to do that using SAM - hopefully it would build the resource (SQS, Lambda function) without doing it manually. The code is very similar to [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-sam-messaging-services-integration/tree/master/1-sqs).

I would like to define all the resource in the `.yml`. After running the `sam deploy` command it created the SQS and Lambda function. After the SQS is created I would update the Lambda code so it would send data using the right SQS URL. However I would like to see if I could automate the whole process (without filling the URL of the newly created SQS).

1. It's possible that the `sam deploy` command would create the Queue the first time and then it would feed the URL directly to lambda.
2. When I went to AWS lambda console, I could see the deployed lambda function. However I couldn't see that the SQS is defined as the destination of the lambda function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wire everything up in one go.

> Is it possible that the sam deploy command would create the Queue the first time and then it would feed the URL directly to lambda?

Yes.  SAM/CloudFormation uses [Intrinsic Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) in your templates to assign values to properties that are not available until runtime.  The `AWS::SQS::Queue` resource [exposes several such properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sqs-queue.html#aws-resource-sqs-queue-return-values).  In the referenced template, for instance, `QueuePublisherFunction` receives the queue URL as an environment variable:

```yaml
Environment:
  Variables:
    SQSqueueName: !Ref MySqsQueue # When you pass the logical ID of this resource to the intrinsic Ref function, Ref returns the queue URL.
```

> When I went to AWS lambda console, I could see the deployed lambda function. However I couldn't see that the SQS is defined as the destination of the lambda function.

That's expected.  If you are following the template, your Lambdas were not configured with a [Destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-eventinvokeconfiguration.html), which has [special meaning in Lambda-speak](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/) (e.g. optionally used in error handling).

Where can you view how the Queue is wired to your Lambda?  Your Queue should be visible in the `QueueConsumerFunction` Lambda console as a "trigger".  Your `QueueConsumerFunction` should be visible in the SQS console as a "Lambda trigger".  Your `QueuePublisherFunction` is not coupled with the queue at the infrastructure level.  It just puts messages in the queue.

Comment: Yeah Thanks I tested that and it worked. The reason why I posted this message is because initally I tried the 'sam local invoke' and it seems that the variable name is not correct. After deploying to the project I found that the variable 'SQSqueueName' is correct.